# How to get notified when network connection changes in Xamarin Forms iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, reachability

I have a requirement in my app where I need to display an image to indicate whether the app is connected to network or not.I was able to do it using the Connectivity Plugin by James Montemagno.But I want to implement it using Reachability class.When I implement the Reachability class the OnChange method never fires.When I turn ON or turn OFF the wifi the OnChange is never called.Can somebody guide me on how to achieve this?

```
 public static event EventHandler ReachabilityChanged;
static void OnChange(NetworkReachabilityFlags flags)
        {
            ReachabilityChanged?.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
```

Comment: If you got it working, then why do you want to do it a different way?

Answer (score 0):

Put below code in your PCL App()

```
CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged += (object sender, Plugin.Connectivity.Abstractions.ConnectivityChangedEventArgs e) =>
{
    bool IsInternetConnected = e.IsConnected;
}
```

You can pass connectivity status using Messaging Center refer [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/)

Answer (score -1):

Ok let me explain how use the Rehability.cs class

1) add this file in your project.

https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/blob/master/ReachabilitySample/reachability.cs

2) change the namespace for the name of your project .

3) Declare this variables in your ViewController like the image [image]

```
 NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus, internetStatus, localWifiStatus;
```

4) In your ViewController add this method . The line TableView.ReloadData (); put the name of your table o item that you wanna update.

```
void UpdateStatus (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        remoteHostStatus = Reachability.RemoteHostStatus ();
        internetStatus = Reachability.InternetConnectionStatus ();
        localWifiStatus = Reachability.LocalWifiConnectionStatus ();
        TableView.ReloadData ();
    }
```

5) In the ViewDidLoad add this two lines

```
        UpdateStatus (null, null);
        Reachability.ReachabilityChanged += UpdateStatus;
```

for a more understand of the code  download this example and run the app in you Visual studio . https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/ReachabilitySample/

Regards