# How to get notified when network connection changes in Xamarin Forms Android?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, android-wifi, wifimanager

I am deploying my XF app at Android 4.4 and basing on [this advise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47055345/8913150)
I am trying to get a notification regarding established Wifi connection. I added CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged in my App.xaml.cs but this event seemed never happened when my application connected to a Wifi network. What did I do wrong? My code is the following:

```
public partial class App : Application {
    public App (IWifiOperations mgr) { 
        InitializeComponent(); MainPage = new MainPage(mgr);
    } 
    protected override void OnStart () {
        CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged += Current_ConnectivityChanged;
    }
    private void Current_ConnectivityChanged(object sender, Plugin.Connectivity.Abstractions.ConnectivityChangedEventArgs e) { 
        var qq = "";
    } 
}
```

Comment: Could you share the code where you added your event? Maybe we see something that you missed.

Comment: This is my code in PCL:  <code>public partial class App : Application
 {
  public App (IWifiOperations mgr)
  {
   InitializeComponent();

   MainPage = new MainPage(mgr);
  }

  protected override void OnStart ()
  {
            CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged += Current_ConnectivityChanged;
        }

        private void Current_ConnectivityChanged(object sender, Plugin.Connectivity.Abstractions.ConnectivityChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var qq = "";
        }
   }
</code>